# {Рython}Почему выдает ошибку, по типу этот объект нельзя вызвать('module' object is not callable)?

Tags: python, type-error

Я знаю что нельзя вызвать модуль который заимпортил, но так сказано в доках + раньше у меня работало. С тех пор я ничего не менял! Ошибка в 6 строке('module' object is not callable)[image: вот]

Comment: Полностью код не читайте, я его еще не дописал)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from InstagramAPI import InstagramAPI
```

и потом уже вызывай, класс лежит в модуле
можешь также вызвать `InstagramAPI.InstagramAPI()`

Comment: Cпасибо, Друг!!!

Comment: @GedJack пожалуйста, в качестве благодарности, можешь пометить мой ответ как верный)

Comment: я тут новенький, на галочку нажать?

Comment: @GedJack ага